# Selenium InvalidSelectorError in a Windows XP VM

Tags: selenium, jruby, watir-webdriver

We have a test automation suite using JRuby 1.7.4, page-object, and Watir-webdriver running against IE8. In our page object for the navigation bar, we have this for our Help link:

```
link(:help, :id => 'menu_help')
```

Everything runs fine on our local machines, but when we deploy it to a Windows VM and run a test that clicks the Help link, we get the following error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError: The xpath expression './/a[@id='menu_help']' cannot be evaluated or does not result in a WebElement
```

This actually happens with any link we try to access, no matter the method we use to find the element in the DOM. I can go to the page myself and see the anchor tag with the correct id in the developer tools. I've ran the follow in the IRB console on the Windows VM and get the same error on the last line:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
@browser.goto '<app url is here>'
link = @browser.link :id => 'menu_help'
link.exists?
```

Now, the only difference I can see is that we're using Windows 7 on our development machines, while our VMs are still running XP. Otherwise, all versions of IEBrowserDriver, JRuby, and watir-webdriver are the same between our development machines and the XP VM. I'm toying with the idea of getting XP Mode and seeing if I can get it to work there, but in the meantime, is there something I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: I installed Windows XP Mode on my machine, set up JRuby with the same versions I'm using on our dev machines and on the other Windows XP VM and it works from there in the IRB, so I'm thinking it might be a configuration issue on the other Windows XP VM.

Comment: What version of IE vs your own version of IE?

Comment: My box: 8.0.7601.17514 --- Windows XP VM: 8.0.6001.18702